# Swift 3 link from date format

Tags: swift, date, hyperlink, format

Solution seems to me very simple, but...

```
let link = "http://example.com/zzz.aspx?d=yyyyMMddt=1"
var dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = link
print(dateformatter.string(from: Date()))
```

I expect to get "http://example.com/zzz.aspx?d=20170403t=1"

Comment: and what did you get? your question is unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All characters in the format string which should be copied verbatim
and not interpreted as date format patterns must be enclosed
in single quotes:

```
let link = "'http://example.com/zzz.aspx?d='yyyyMMdd't=1'"
var dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = link
print(dateformatter.string(from: Date()))

// http://example.com/zzz.aspx?d=20170403t=1
```